# How do I toggle <td> 'table data cells' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, show-hide

So I need to be able to click to show/hide table data cells, however, after trying multiple functions for toggling their display I've been unable to progress forward in my attempts.

Although I've tried several different functions I keep getting the same error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle_visibilityOn is not defined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick

Here is the latest iteration of my code in PHP.

```
if($job_type != 'Maintenance'){ ?> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <!--<td><a href="edit-job-2.php?job=<?php echo $job_id; ?>">-->
                                            <td onclick = "toggle_visibilityOn(<?php echo $job_id; ?>)"><?php echo $job_id; ?>

                                            <td id = "billingticket<?php echo $job_id; ?>"><?php echo $billing_ticket; ?></td>
                                            <td id = "billing_status<?php echo $billing_status; ?>"><?php echo $billing_status; ?></td>
                                            <td id = "job_date<?php echo $job_date; ?>"></td>
                                            <td id = "drilling_contractor<?php echo $drilling_contractor; ?>"><?php echo $drilling_contractor; ?></td>
                                            <td id = "job_type<?php echo $job_type; ?>"><?php echo $job_type; ?></td>
                                            <td id = "lease_name<?php echo $lease_name; ?>"><?php echo $lease_name; ?></td>
                                            <td id = "job_status<?php echo $job_status; ?>"><?php echo $job_status; ?></td>
                                            </td>
                                        <tr>



                            <?php   }
```

I have commented out the previous attempts.
Here is the Javascript portion of the code:

```
    function toggle_visibilityOn()
{
    document.getElementById("billing_status<?php echo $billing_status; ?>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("job_date<?php echo $job_date; ?>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("drilling_contractor><?php echo $drilling_contractor; ?>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("job_type<?php echo $job_type; ?>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("lease_name<?php echo $lease_name; ?>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("job_status<?php echo $job_status; ?>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("billingticket<?php echo $job_id; ?>").setAttribute('onclick','toggle_visibilityOff()');
    document.getElementById("billingticket<?php echo $job_id; ?>");
}

function toggle_visibilityOff()
{
    document.getElementById("billing_status<?php echo $billing_status; ?>").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("job_date<?php echo $job_date; ?>").style.display = "block";    
    document.getElementById("drilling_contractor<?php echo $drilling_contractor; ?>").style.display = "block";  
    document.getElementById("job_type<?php echo $job_type; ?>").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("lease_name<?php echo $lease_name; ?>").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("job_status<?php echo $job_status; ?>").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("billingticket<?php echo $job_id; ?>").setAttribute('onclick','toggle_visibilityOn()');
    document.getElementById("billingticket<?php echo $job_id; ?>");
```

}

I know I'm doing something wrong, and I'm almost sure it has to do with the Id tags, but I'm no closer to figuring it out than I was two days ago.

Note: I'm fixing and editing preexisting code so I'm not familiar with everything that's going on. I'm aware the answer may lie elsewhere.

To anyone who reads this: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot we can do to make this better. First, you shouldn't `echo` the jobID in the javascript -- you should pass the value via the onClick method. Next, we can combine both of your toggle methods into one simplified version. Lastly, unless you want your table columns to be stacked, you won't want to use `display: block` for the toggleOn -- use `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`.

Here's an example with your PHP removed so that it can demonstrate the functionality of the javascript.

```js
function toggle_visibility(jobID) {
  const billingTicket = document.getElementById("billingticket" + jobID);
  const style = (billingTicket.style.display === "none") ? "inline-block" : "none";
  
  billingTicket.style.display = style;
  document.getElementById("billing_status" + jobID).style.display = style;
  document.getElementById("job_date" + jobID).style.display = style;
  document.getElementById("drilling_contractor" + jobID).style.display = style;
  document.getElementById("job_type" + jobID).style.display = style;
  document.getElementById("lease_name" + jobID).style.display = style;
  document.getElementById("job_status" + jobID).style.display = style;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="toggle_visibility(5)">JOBID 5</td>
    <td id="billingticket5">Billing Ticket</td>
    <td id="billing_status5">Billing Status</td>
    <td id="job_date5">Job Date</td>
    <td id="drilling_contractor5">Drilling Contractor</td>
    <td id="job_type5">Job Type</td>
    <td id="lease_name5">Lease Name</td>
    <td id="job_status5">Job Status</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just put your PHP back into the table structure here and you should be good to go.

---

If this is exactly how you want the data in your table to be laid out, we can simplify this even more:

```js
function toggle_visibility(element) {
  [...element.parentNode.children].splice(1).forEach(column => {
    column.style.display = column.style.display === 'none' ? "inline-block" : "none";
  });

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">JOBID 5</td>
    <td>Billing Ticket</td>
    <td>Billing Status</td>
    <td>Job Date</td>
    <td>Drilling Contractor</td>
    <td>Job Type</td>
    <td>Lease Name</td>
    <td>Job Status</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is even better because it doesn't require the elementID's, and so you also won't need to clutter your PHP file with all those `echos`.

What I'm doing here is using the context of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to pass in the element that was clicked. Then we get an array of the element's siblings by using [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax to create an array from the `children` object of the `parentNode`, and `splice` the array to remove the first child from the array, leaving us with an array that contains all of the siblings of the element that was clicked. Finally we loop through each member of the array to toggle the display style of each sibling.

---

If you need a button that can toggle all of these types of rows, try this example:

```js
function toggle_visibility(element) {
  [...element.parentNode.children].splice(1).forEach(column => {
    column.style.display = column.style.display === 'none' ? "inline-block" : "none";
  });

  //check if all rows are hidden/shown to update button label
  let comparison,
    shouldUpdateButtonLabel = true,
    rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  [...rows].forEach(row => {
    if (!comparison) comparison = row.children[1].style.display;
    else if (row.children[1].style.display !== comparison) shouldUpdateButtonLabel = false;
  });

  if (shouldUpdateButtonLabel) {
    let button = document.getElementById("toggleAll");
    button.innerHTML = button.innerHTML === "Hide All" ? "Show All" : "Hide All";
  }
}

function toggleAll(button) {
  const style = button.innerHTML === "Hide All" ? "none" : "inline-block";
  button.innerHTML = button.innerHTML === "Hide All" ? "Show All" : "Hide All";

  let rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  [...rows].forEach(row => {
    [...row.children].splice(1).forEach(column => {
      column.style.display = style;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
td {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">JOBID 5</td>
    <td>Billing Ticket</td>
    <td>Billing Status</td>
    <td>Job Date</td>
    <td>Drilling Contractor</td>
    <td>Job Type</td>
    <td>Lease Name</td>
    <td>Job Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">JOBID 6</td>
    <td>Billing Ticket</td>
    <td>Billing Status</td>
    <td>Job Date</td>
    <td>Drilling Contractor</td>
    <td>Job Type</td>
    <td>Lease Name</td>
    <td>Job Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="toggle_visibility(this)">JOBID 7</td>
    <td>Billing Ticket</td>
    <td>Billing Status</td>
    <td>Job Date</td>
    <td>Drilling Contractor</td>
    <td>Job Type</td>
    <td>Lease Name</td>
    <td>Job Status</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="toggleAll" onclick="toggleAll(this)">Hide All</button>
```

Comment: Was just typing up the same thing, but being unfamiliar with PHP, had to go check I was right about the `<? php echo...>` commands.

Comment: It's working! But I have a new issue. I have several of these rows, each with a unique job id. I need to be able to show and hide each one. That is to say, I need to apply the function to all of them. I've gotten it to work this way before, but I ran into the same issue.

Comment: @Sramirez no problem, glad I could be of assistance :) Check out the edit I just made to my answer. The last example, which I just added, includes a button which would allow you to show/hide all of the data columns. If this solves your issue, please consider marking this as the accepted answer and/or upvoting.

Comment: This is working pretty good, I'm getting closer to what I need and I've learned a lot. Is there any way to make it work for each one individually? As in, click on each ID and it hides/shows.

Comment: Try my examples, they already do this. For instance in my last example, click any of the texts from the first column (the IDs).

Comment: I just added something I had not originally thought about. Now when you individually toggle all rows to the same display style, it will also update the button label. Example: button reads “Hide All” and you start clicking each row to hide it, when you’ve hidden them all the button will change to “Show All”.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I've learned a lot. I appreciate it. There's more to do on this, but I'll be able to figure out the rest. I like how clean your code is, it's something I'll try to imitate from here on out.

Comment: One more question, I forgot to ask how to have it all default hidden. It needs to be hidden first and then show. I'm still working on it and reading articles and trying different things, but I'm not there yet.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that out. Once again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Great no problem!